# Error setting preferences in eclipse for ADT

Tags: eclipse, adt

I installed eclipse Juno and android development toolkit(ADT) plugin on that. After installing the plugin, when I try to set preferences for ADT, I get this error:

Unable to create the selected preference page.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (428).

I used this page as reference for installing plugin:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

Please suggest something

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem - on restarting Eclipse, it went away. You may also need to clean your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. Uninstalling the ADT plugin and re-installing worked for me. 
Hope this helps!